# How to achieve this effect, RecyclerView can be stopped precisely

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2

I don't know how to describe it, it looks like a RecyclerView that stops scrolling when the next Item part is displayed (about 200dp). I'm trying to measure the size of the next Item displayed in `RecyclerView.addOnScrollListener` to control the `RecyclerView` sliding state.

But the RecycleView callback onScrollStateChanged while flinging is not precise enough (the sliding callback is something like 1,20,50) to determine the exact position when sliding fast, in fact, I tried `RecyclerView` and `NestedScrollView`.

Here's a video of the screen recording.

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/appdev/gallery@master/img/2022-07-07/ebP9do.mp4

[image: yt0xA3]

When scrolling fast, it can stop when the next item is partially displayed.

[image]

You can just drag up and load the next one. Or you can keep dragging up. Like this

[image]

Comment: have you tried "scrollToPosition" instead https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager#scrollToPosition(int) ? or smoothScroll https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager#smoothScrollToPosition(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView,%20androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.State,%20int) i.e. instead of stopping using the size, use the position.

Comment: My main problem is that the RecyclerView can stop after the next Item is partially displayed.

Comment: Is it viewpager2 or recyclerview!?